# Spring integration - Keep messages after delivery

Tags: spring, messaging, spring-integration, spring-data-mongodb

1) I'm interested to learn if it is possible to keep the messages that were delivered using Spring Integration. I'm already using the mongo persistent storage (ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore), but only failed messages remain in the collection. Ideally, I want all messages to remain with the functionality to list them and retry them.

I would use a field "status" or similar to identify queued, succesful or failed messages. Not sure if this field exists already, but I'm guessing something similar must be in place.

2) Also, when a message fails and is persited, there is a lot more data in the message. This data is serialised, so I'm curious how I can extract the original message and retry it.

3) The goal is to create an interface in the webapp where all queued messages can be seen, and retried. Not only failed messages, but also succesful deliveries (useful for testing).

I looked everywhere for an answer to this, but could not find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it isn't good design for `queue` component.

Right it returns failed messages to the queue back for the future redelivery, but good message should be removed from the queue to avoid duplication on the next poll from queue.

No, there is no  "status" field on the message, because you use store as a queue.

BTW Spring Integration provides separete implementation for queue channels: `MongoDbChannelMessageStore`.

You can achieve it with separate parallel Mongo collection and store your message twice: for the queue and for the future analysis. Here you can introduce "status" field and control it, when message successful or not.

From here you can introduce you UI to manage that collection and provide actions like `send`, `retry`. Remove the message from here and send it again to those two collections.

HTH

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution. Any idea how to re-send the saved error messages? They are not picked up automatically...

Comment: You should distinguish `queue poll` and `message process`. No one message should remain in the queue. The further process can determine, if message OK or not and mark it in that separete collection.